# How to solve the equation $x^2-2x=\sqrt{ 2x^2-4x+3} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the equation $x^2-2x=\sqrt{ 2x^2-4x+3} $

Will squaring both sides introduce a $x^4$ term that may complicate the equation?

Comment: I'd start by squaring both sides.

Comment: Change $x^2-2x=t$

Comment: Please show your attempts...

Comment: Will squaring both sides create a $ x^4 $ that may complicate the equation?

Comment: @UrošKosmač That is wrong. See any of the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sqrt{2x^2 - 4x + 3} = \sqrt{2(x^2 - 2x) + 3}$$

Let $v = x^2 - 2x$.

$$\implies x^2 - 2x = \sqrt{2(x^2 - 2x) + 3}\longrightarrow v = \sqrt{2v + 3}$$

Square both sides to get

$$v^2 = 2v + 3 \\ v^2 - 2v - 3 = 0$$

Solve the quadratic equation to find the roots of $v$ and then undo the substitution to find the values of $x$ when $v > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint

Let $\sqrt{2x^2-4x+3}=a\ge0$

$2(x^2-2x)=a^2-3$

Answer (score 1):

Squaring both sides we have $^4-4x^3+4x^2$=$2x^2-4x+3$ and collecting like terms we have $x^4-4x^3+2x^2+4x-3=0$. By inspection x=-1 and x=1 is a solution hence we have $x^4-4x^3+2x^2+4x-3$=$(x^2-1)(x^2-4x+3)$=$(x-1)(x+1)(x-1)(x-3)$=0. So we have found the four roots, but remember since we have squared both sides we have introduced two new solutions. Substituting back into the original equation we see that x=1 (repeated root) is not the correct solution since it gives a negative value under the square root.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question: yes, squaring introduces additional "sol.utions" which you do not want. So you have to check at the end.

Squaring gives $(x^2-2x)^2-2(x^2-2x)-3=0$ or $$(x^2-2x-3)(x^2-2x+1)=0$$ so $x=1,-1$ or $3$.

But checking we find that $x=1$ is not a solution to the original equation.